# Accessing two levels in my plist file

Tags: xcode, plist

I have a plist file that contains country, state, city.  I can access the country level for the pickers, but I cannot seem to get the state and city populated.  I have created a plist file with the following: country --> dictionary, state--> dictionary, and city --> array.

The code is:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"placesdictionary" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
self.places = dictionary;
NSArray *componentsCountry = [self.places allKeys];
NSArray *sortedCountry = [componentsCountry sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
self.country = sortedCountry;
NSString *selectedCountry = [country objectAtIndex:0];
```

This is fine.  But the following code has errors:

```
NSArray *componentsState = [self.places allKeysForObject:selectedCountry];
NSArray *sortedState = [componentsState sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
self.state = sortedState;
NSString *selectedState = [state objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *componentsCity = [self.places objectForKey:selectedState];
NSArray *sortedCity = [componentsCity sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
self.city = sortedCity;
```

Can you please help me with the problems?  Thank you.

This is my plist file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>France</key>
        <dict>
            <key>state 3</key>
            <array>
                <string>Paris</string>
            </array>
            <key>state 2</key>
            <array>
                <string>Nice</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>US</key>
        <dict>
            <key>california</key>
            <array>
                <string>LA</string>
                <string>San Fran</string>
                <string>San Diego</string>
            </array>
            <key>new jersey</key>
            <array>
                <string>riverdale</string>
                <string>newark</string>
                </array>
        </dict>
     </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: country, state, city - are on one level in your plist? Or state is in country?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>France</key>
 <dict>
  <key>state 3</key>
  <array>
   <string>Paris</string>
  </array>
  <key>state 2</key>
  <array>
   <string>Nice</string>
  </array>
 </dict>
 <key>US</key>
 <dict>
  <key>california</key>
  <array>
   <string>LA</string>
   <string>San Fran</string>
   <string>San Diego</string>
  </array>
 </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice to use such code for accessing plist data:

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"placesdictionary" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSMutableDictionary *properties = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
NSDictionary *france = (NSDictionary *)[properties valueForKey:@"France"]; 
// if cities is in countries then you can access them using [countries valueForKey:@"cityName"];
NSArray *cities = [france valueForKey:@"state 3"];
```

Comment: But, I am using the data in a picker.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. The code above will grant access to your plist data.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time with my problem.  The data will be in a picker with three columns (one column for the countries, one for the states, and one for the cities).  The code you have given to me works, except for the cities.  I will use it to figure this out.  Thanks again.