# How to access multi level structured Plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsmutabledictionary

How can I access a particular week plan from a plist with this format?
If any one knows any tutorial related to multilevel structured plist please suggest.

The following code gives me the entire data stored in Plist

```
-(void)ReadAppPlist
{
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"runplan" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary * propertyDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]    initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    name = [propertyDict objectForKey:@"Run - 1"];

    NSLog(@"%@",name.description);  
}
```

The plist is in the format given below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Run - 1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Level</key>
            <string>Beginner</string>
            <key>Category</key>
            <string>5K</string>
            <key>Plan</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Duration</key>
                <string>5week</string>
                <key>Week 1</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Day 1</key>
                    <string>Rest or run/walk</string>
                    <key>Day 2</key>
                    <string>2.5 km run</string>
                    <key>Day 3</key>
                    <string>Rest or run/walk</string>
                    <key>Day 4</key>
                    <string>2.5 km run</string>
                    <key>Day 5</key>
                    <string>Rest</string>
                    <key>Day 6</key>
                    <string>2.5 km run</string>
                    <key>Day 7</key>
                    <string>30 - 60 min walk</string>
                </dict>
                <key>Week 2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Day 1</key>
                    <string>Rest or run/walk</string>
                    <key>Day 2</key>
                    <string>3 km run</string>
                    <key>Day 3</key>
                    <string>Rest or run/walk</string>
                    <key>Day 4</key>
                    <string>2.5 km run</string>
                    <key>Day 5</key>
                    <string>Rest</string>
                    <key>Day 6</key>
                    <string>3 km run</string>
                    <key>Day 7</key>
                    <string>35 - 60 min walk</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

I don't know how to retrieve those data so kindly please help me if any one knows the solution...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Run -1* has a String (*Beginner*) for key *Level*, a String (*5K*) for key *Category*, a Dictionary for key *Plan*, etc.

Comment: yes it has all the details like level, category, plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this way we can traverse to the inner structure of our plist file...

```
-(void)ReadAppPlist{
        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"runplan" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSMutableDictionary * propertyDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        //name1 dictionary will have the entire content of plist
        NSDictionary *name1 = (NSDictionary *)[propertyDict objectForKey:@"Run - 1"];
        // here we are traversing to inner structure of elements.
        NSDictionary *level=[name1 objectForKey:@"Level"];
        NSDictionary *category=[name1 objectForKey:@"Category"];
        NSDictionary *plan=[name1 objectForKey:@"Plan"];
        NSDictionary *week=[plan objectForKey:@"Week 1"];
        NSDictionary *Day=[week objectForKey:@"Day 1"];

        NSLog(@"LEVEL %@",level);
        NSLog(@"CATEGORY %@",category);
        NSLog(@"Week Plan %@",week);
        NSLog(@"Day Plan %@",Day);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Using this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238693/1671729)

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"runplan" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSMutableDictionary *properties = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistPath mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];

//Now get the nested dictionary for the key "Run - 1"
NSDictionary *name = (NSDictionary *)[properties valueForKey:@"Run - 1"];

//Now get the nested dictionary for the key "Week 1"
NSDictionary *name2 = (NSDictionary *)[name valueForKey:@"Week 1"];
```

Basically you can traverse the hierarchy getting dictionaries for `valueForKey:`.

Comment: name returning entire plist & name2 returning null value.

Comment: I was using the wrong string for the key.  I had "Week - 1" but your pList is "Week 1".  Updated.